# Reading from a pty

Tags: c, pty

I'd like to receive (and later process) `write(1)` and `wall(1)` messages using a (Unix 98-style) pseudo tty on Linux.
I already have the following minimal implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <utempter.h>

#define BUF_LENGTH 1024

int
main (void)
{
    FILE *lf;
    int masterfd, slavefd;
    char *slave_name = NULL;
    char buf[BUF_LENGTH];
    size_t nbytes = sizeof(buf);
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    int exit_code = EXIT_SUCESS;

    if ((masterfd = posix_openpt (O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY)) == -1 
            || grantpt (masterfd) == -1
            || unlockpt (masterfd) == -1
            || (slave_name = ptsname (masterfd)) == NULL)
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (!(lf = fopen("term.log","w")))
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

    addToUtmp (slave_name, NULL, masterfd);

    for (;;)
    {
        bytes_read = read(masterfd, buf, nbytes);
        if (bytes_read <= 0)
            break
        fwrite (buf, 1, bytes_read, lf);
    }

    if (bytes_read < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "error reading from master pty: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        exit_code = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fclose (lf);
    if (slavefd >= 0)
        close (slavefd);
    if (masterfd >= 0)
    {
        removeLineFromUtmp (slave_name, masterfd);
        close (masterfd);
    }
    exit (exit_code);
}
```

The problem is now that it only works for reading the first message, then read gives me a EIO error. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this happens simply when the last slave file descriptor is closed. Considering `write(1)` and `wall(1)` will have the only file descriptor to the slave, you get EIO as soon as those finish writing.

The easiest way to keep this from happening is by keeping a file descriptor around. Right after your `ptsname` call, do an `open(slave_name, O_RDRW)`.

(Curiously, you already have a `slavefd` variable, and the code to clean it up. Are you testing us? :p)

Comment: D'oh, I must have accidentally deleted the open line while experimenting (as you noticed the fd variable and cleanup is already in there). Thanks a lot, another pair of eyes can sometimes be very helpful:)